# ListView Baseadapter notifyDataSetChanged() not working

Tags: android, listview

I have list view inside view pager. When i update the list and try to update list view through notifyDataSetChanged(), it didn't work and not update list. First List async task called to get list and then LoadMoreList to get more data.

if i take the list view outside the view pager than notifyDataSetChanged is working but inside view pager not.

```
private class List extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<String> loadMoreList;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        loadMoreList = WebFunctions.getEventList();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String string) {
        if(loadMoreList != null){
            eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);
            adapter = new myPagerAdapter(thisContext, eventList);
            myPager.setAdapter(adapter );

            }
    }
}
```

Async task to get more data.

```
private class LoadMoreList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<String> loadMoreList;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        loadMoreList = WebFunctions.getEventList();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String string) {
        if(loadMoreList != null){
            eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } 
    }
}
```

View pager adapter

```
 //Custom pager adapter
private class myPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    ArrayList<String> eventlist;
    private final Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public myPagerAdapter (Context context , ArrayList<String> events)
    {
        this.eventlist = events;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return eventlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

        final LinearLayout page = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, null);

        listView = (ListView) page.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myAdapter = new myAdapter(eventList);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(page);

        return page;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

and here is myAdpter

```
 //list adapter
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<ContactMoadel> contact;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<String> contactlist) {
        this.contact = contactlist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contact.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        retrun convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get more data, you call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. What is `myAdapter` and where does it get set?

Comment: I have added myAdapter. It is been set in view pager adapter(myPagerAdapter)

Comment: is LoadMoreList  a inner class of myPagerAdapter ?

Comment: No its not. Its called when list reached to end cell.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. In the code for `LoadMoreList.onPostExecute()` you call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. What is `myAdapter` in this context? Is this a member variable of the class `LoadMoreList`? Where is this variable defined and where it it set to a value. I don't see any code in `LoadMoreList` that sets this to anything.

Comment: As a side note, you really should stick to standard Java naming conventions: You have classes named `myAdapterextends` and `myPagerAdapter`. Class names should always begin with an **uppercase letter** to distinguish them from variable names (which should always begin with a **lowercase letter**).

Comment: Shouldn't you be updating the same adapter? In the loadMoreList async task, shouldn't you be doing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ? Why do you have two different adapters ?

Comment: myAdapter is type of list adapter and declared globaly. myAdapter initiates on myPagerAdapter. and when more elements added in eventlist, i want to notify adapter to update list view from exactly that point where async task is called. but list is not updating.

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() update the pager adapter but i wanted to notify list adapter.

Comment: if i take the list view outside the view pager than notifyDataSetChanged is working but inside view pager not.

Answer (score 0):

- I think there may be problem because you are returning null from doInBackground method, change return value to loadMoreList

@Override

```
public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
  loadMoreList = WebFunctions.getEventList();

  return loadMoreList;
}
```

Comment: Loadmorelist is a array list and i am adding it to eventlist.
 eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);

Comment: then return loadMoreList, and change return type of doInBackground from string to List<typeofloadMoreList>.

Comment: No effect. Still adapter not updating

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I should have set adapter when i am getting the eventlist first time.
In List async task

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute() {
    if(loadMoreList != null){
        eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);
        myAdapter = new myAdapter(thisContext, eventList);  
}
```

and in LoadMoreList

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute() {
    if(loadMoreList != null){
        eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

View Pager adapter should be like this

```
 //Custom pager adapter
private class myPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    ArrayList<String> eventlist;
    private final Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public myPagerAdapter (Context context , ArrayList<String> events)
   {
       this.eventlist = events;
       this.context = context;
       this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return eventlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

        final LinearLayout page = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list,   null);

        listView = (ListView) page.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(page);

        return page;
   }
   @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
  }
}
```